# Does hibernate implicitly rolls back when delete func is called or is there a need to call it explicitly?

Tags: hibernate

Does hibernate implicitly rolls back when delete function (then flush afterwards) is called when exception occurrs? I have this code below

```
line 1: try {
line 2:  session.beginTransaction();
line 3:  session.delete(entity);
line 4:  session.flush(); //Is there a need for this if i'm going to commit
                          //the transaction anyway?
                          //Is rollback implicitly called when exception occurs?
                          //Do i still need line 5 to be able to rollback?

line 5:  session.getTransaction.commit(); //What happens when this line and line 7
                                          //do not exist and exception was thrown?  
line 6: } catch (Throwable t) {
line 7:  session.getTransaction.rollback();
line 8: }
```

When you don't have lines 2, 5, and 7, the entity will still be deleted right? But what happens when an exception occurs?

Your inputs are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the documentation?
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/transactions.html

> 11.2.1. Non-managed environment
>   ...
>   You do not have to flush() the Session explicitly: the call to commit() automatically triggers the synchronization depending on the FlushMode for the session. A call to close() marks the end of a session. The main implication of close() is that the JDBC connection will be relinquished by the session. This Java code is portable and runs in both non-managed and JTA environments. 
>   ...
>   11.2.2. Using JTA
>   ...
>   If you use bean-managed transactions (BMT), Hibernate will tell the application server to start and end a BMT transaction if you use the Transaction API. *The transaction management code is identical to the non-managed environment.*

I added the emphasis to answer the questions in your code.

As for transactions: hibernate will use the existing transaction, i.e. when the transaction commits, so will hibernate. When it rolls back, the database transaction is also rolled back, including any flushes done... I think.

Comment: i see. but when you dont use the transaction and just simply executed line 3 and 4, the entity will still be deleted from the db right? but what happens when an exception occurred?